# failed to add. react-native-vector-icons

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, yarnpkg, react-native-vector-icons

W trying to add `react-native-vector-icons` into my app.

This is what I'm doing:

1. `yarn add react-native-vector-icons`
2. `react-native link react-native-vector-icons`
3. Open Xcode project and create new group inside the root called Files.
4. Into the files folder I paste all fonts inside `node_modules/react-native-vector-itens`
5. And add this rows into `info.plist` file:

   ```xml
   <key>UIAppFonts</key>
       <array>
           <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
           <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
           <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
           <string>Feather.ttf</string>
           <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
           <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
           <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
           <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
           <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
           <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
           <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
           <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
           <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
           <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
           <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
           <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
       </array>
   ```
6. `cd ios -> pod install`.
7. `yarn ios`
8. I got this exception for each added font:

   ```
   Build system information
   error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/flavio.luiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/grdiariesapp-glxxnoufhzcqqqehxmwglijwtgap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/grdiariesapp.app/FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf':
   1) Target 'grdiariesapp' (project 'grdiariesapp') has copy command from '/Users/flavio.luiz/Documents/learning/grdiariesapp/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf' to '/Users/flavio.luiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/grdiariesapp-glxxnoufhzcqqqehxmwglijwtgap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/grdiariesapp.app/FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf'
   2) That command depends on command in Target 'grdiariesapp' (project 'grdiariesapp'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
   ```

Can anyone help?

Comment: just delete the files you put in xcode manually after 0.60 you don't need to do that.

Comment: Yeap! It worked.  Do you wanna reply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For versions < 0.60 you should put the files manually.

Version > 0.60 autolinking will do the job so in your case you duplicate it so just delete the files you intrudoce and all will work as expected.